# 500 questions :)

Tags: discussion

This question is just to congratulate this community for the first of many 500 questions :-)

[image]

Despite this awesomeness. We should worry about the Area51 metrics:

```
1.1 questions per day              | Needs Work
94% answered                       | Excellent  
72 avid users && 2,527 total users | Needs Work
2.5 answer ratio                   | Excellent 
620 visits/day                     | Okay
```

Comment: The metrics are steadily improving, but the one that would probably help all around is the number of questions asked per day.

Comment: Don't forget to vote! That's one of the best ways to encourage participation.

Comment: +1 @blah238. There is not enough voting.

Comment: And to select an answer to questions that you've asked.